# Getting an error "COPY failed: stat /home/app/target/Service.jar : file does not exist" in multistage docker build

Tags: docker, gitlab, dockerfile, gitlab-ci, docker-registry

My Docker File is,

```
FROM maven:3.6.0-jdk-11-slim AS build

COPY src /home/app/src

COPY pom.xml /home/app

RUN mvn -f /home/app/pom.xml clean package


FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim

COPY --from=build /home/app/target/Service.jar /usr/local/lib/Service.jar

EXPOSE 8081

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/usr/local/lib/service.jar"]
```

When executing COPY --from line, getting an error "COPY failed: stat /home/app/target/Service.jar : file does not exist".

Note: when we execute "RUN ls /home/app" command, its listing Files and target directory .

Could someone help on this.

Comment: The file does not exisit. You could `RUN ls -lisa /home/app/target` after `RUN mvn -f ...` to list the content of the `target` folder.

Comment: when we execute "RUN ls /home/app" command, its listing Files and target directory .

Comment: Does it list a `Service.jar` in `/home/app/target`?

Comment: Right, so does the `target` directory have a `Service.jar` file (from `RUN ls /home/app/target`, I would assume)?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a `finalName` defined in your pom?

```
<build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
...
```

if not the resulting artifact will have versioning in the name and will not be called `Service.jar` but something like `Service-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

```
FROM maven:3.6.0-jdk-11-slim AS build
COPY src /home/app/src
COPY pom.xml /home/app/pom.xml
WORKDIR /home/app
RUN mvn clean package


FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim
COPY --from=build /home/app/target/Service_AND_VERSION_STUFF.jar /usr/local/lib/Service.jar
EXPOSE 8081
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/usr/local/lib/Service.jar"]
```

don't forget to always use the same casing (Sevice != service)

Comment: We should not post speculative answers. We should rather ask for clarification in the comments.

Comment: @Turing85 I normally agree but I was quite convinced the answer was going in this direction...

Comment: It still would not hurt to first as in the comments if OP has set a final name and then post the answer. Besides, I would recommend to not change the `finalName` and rather modify the dockerfile

Comment: thanks a lot. I copied the Dockerfile from somwhere and the artifact name was different in my pom.